# Set Tabulator Title and Field values Dynamically from Json response

Tags: json, tabulator

I am using Tabulator 4.1 ,I have json response returned from ajax,From that i have to show values in tabulator.the problem here is the cointaining json data changed every time (i.e)

```
[{
    "AGENCYID": "-1",
    "TOTALREQUEST": 1
},
{
    "AGENCYID": "-1",
    "TOTALREQUEST": 2
}]
```

here the key and values may be increased. So,accordingly display those values in tabulator ,I have tried set title and filed values dynamically in tabulator but none worked.Below I have attached JS fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/harifrais/vzxt1r4e/15/

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/harifrais/vzxt1r4e/15/][1] 404 not found error in the url

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your Js fiddle url

```js
var jsonres = [
 {
  "AGENCYID": "-1",
  "TOTALREQUEST": 1
 },
 {
  "AGENCYID": "-1",
  "TOTALREQUEST": 2
 },
 {
  "AGENCYID": "-1",
  "TOTALREQUEST": 3
 }
];






var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: jsonres, //load row data from array
  autoColumns: true

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</body>

</html>
```